# Using perf with node - view Javascript functions

Tags: node.js, perf

Is it possible to get information about JavaScript functions with perf?

```
sudo perf node index.js
sudo perf report
```

yields a lot of info about the C++ side.

However, is it possible to measure JavaScript functions as well?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `perf record node index.js`?  There is no `perf node` - if there was it would probably do what you want. :P

All `perf record` can see is machine code executing at some address, and look those addresses up to mappings of executables and libraries, and from there get C++ symbol names.

JIT-compiled JS functions will be in anonymous buffers with no way for perf to map them back to their JS names.  If you see a "hot" function without a name in the `perf report` list, you'll have to manually look at the asm and figure out what it's doing to figure out which JS function it was JIT-compiled from.